# Is it possible to give effects to falling blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to build a "rocket" out of concrete powder. I have a command block that gives a levitation effect to entities within 5 blocks of the command block. This is how I have the rocket set up:

Top layer: 2x2 square of concrete powder.

Layer 0: 2x2 piston door that is sideways.

On the press of a button, the piston door opens, causing the concrete powder to become an entity and fall. The command block activates, giving all entities within 5 blocks of it Levitation 255 for 1 second. However, I only get levitated, and the blocks just fall and plop onto the ground. The concrete powder **is** in range of the command block, but it won't fly up into the air. Is it possible to add status effects to falling block entities (i.e. sand, gravel, concrete powder, and/or primed TNT)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this by placing a command block with the `/effect` command with a pressure plate on top. I would look up, place a sand block next to a fixed block, and exit fly mode so that I would land on the pressure plate while it is falling.

Result in Bedrock Edition:

```
Falling Block cannot have effects
Block of TNT cannot have effects
```

Result in Java Edition

```
Unable to apply this effect (target is either immune to effects, or has something stronger)
```

Therefore, falling blocks and blocks of TNT cannot have effects.

I would also like to take this opportunity to remind you that if you want to give a target an effect they already have but at a weaker level, you will need to remove the effect first in Java Edition. You don't need to in Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Does "Block of TNT" mean that it is primed (it is flashing)?

Comment: So if I wanted to make a rocket using such commands, what would be an optimal solution?

Comment: Ok, so what method do you think would be the best in Java Edition?